# Apply a recursive CTE on grouped table rows (SQL server 2005)

Tags: sql-server-2005, recursive-query

I have a table (ROOMUSAGE) containing the times people check in and out of rooms grouped by PERSONKEY and ROOMKEY. It looks like this:

```
PERSONKEY | ROOMKEY | CHECKIN           | CHECKOUT         | ROW
----------------------------------------------------------------
1         | 8       |  13-4-2010 10:00  | 13-4-2010 11:00  | 1
1         | 8       |  13-4-2010 08:00  | 13-4-2010 09:00  | 2

1         | 1       |  13-4-2010 15:00  | 13-4-2010 16:00  | 1
1         | 1       |  13-4-2010 14:00  | 13-4-2010 15:00  | 2
1         | 1       |  13-4-2010 13:00  | 13-4-2010 14:00  | 3

13        | 2       |  13-4-2010 15:00  | 13-4-2010 16:00  | 1
13        | 2       |  13-4-2010 15:00  | 13-4-2010 16:00  | 2
```

I want to select just the consecutive rows for each PERSONKEY, ROOMKEY grouping. So the desired resulting table is:

```
PERSONKEY | ROOMKEY | CHECKIN           | CHECKOUT         | ROW
----------------------------------------------------------------
1         | 8       |  13-4-2010 10:00  | 13-4-2010 11:00  | 1

1         | 1       |  13-4-2010 15:00  | 13-4-2010 16:00  | 1
1         | 1       |  13-4-2010 14:00  | 13-4-2010 15:00  | 2
1         | 1       |  13-4-2010 13:00  | 13-4-2010 14:00  | 3

13        | 2       |  13-4-2010 15:00  | 13-4-2010 16:00  | 1
```

I want to avoid using cursors so I thought I would use a recursive CTE. Here is what I came up with:

```
;with CTE (PERSONKEY, ROOMKEY, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, ROW)
as (select RU.PERSONKEY,
           RU.ROOMKEY, 
           RU.CHECKIN,
           RU.CHECKOUT,
           RU.ROW
    from ROOMUSAGE RU
    where RU.ROW = 1

    union all

    select RU.PERSONKEY,
           RU.ROOMKEY, 
           RU.CHECKIN,
           RU.CHECKOUT,
           RU.ROW
    from ROOMUSAGE RU inner join CTE on RU.ROW = CTE.ROW + 1
    where CTE.CHECKIN = RU.CHECKOUT
      and CTE.PERSONKEY = RU.PERSONKEY
      and CTE.ROOMKEY = RU.ROOMKEY)
```

This worked OK for very small datasets (under 100 records) but it's unusable on large datasets.

I'm thinking that I should somehow apply the cte recursevely on each PERSONKEY, ROOMKEY grouping on my ROOMUSAGE table but I am not sure how to do that.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Cheers!

Comment: have you looked at the query plan for this, I'd bet that the inner join of RU to CTE is doing table scans the way you are joining it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to try

- Instead of joining with **every** row and filtering the results in your where clause, could you try if reducing the amount of records directly in the join speeds things up?
- Add a covering index on PersonKey, RoomKey, CheckOut & Row and see if it improves performance.

**SQL Statement**

```
;with CTE (PERSONKEY, ROOMKEY, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, ROW)
as (select RU.PERSONKEY,
           RU.ROOMKEY, 
           RU.CHECKIN,
           RU.CHECKOUT,
           RU.ROW
    from ROOMUSAGE RU
    where RU.ROW = 1

    union all

    select RU.PERSONKEY,
           RU.ROOMKEY, 
           RU.CHECKIN,
           RU.CHECKOUT,
           RU.ROW
    from ROOMUSAGE RU 
         inner join CTE on CTE.ROW + 1 = RU.ROW
                           and CTE.CHECKIN = RU.CHECKOUT
                           and CTE.PERSONKEY = RU.PERSONKEY
                           and CTE.ROOMKEY = RU.ROOMKEY
)
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified ROOMUSAGE is another non recursive cte which is created just before CTE. The underlying tables are all indexed. 

I have tried your suggestion and noticed that when I do a select * from CTE, I get all the ROW = 1 rows and then it gets stuck processing the rest of the rows. When I remove the PERSONKEY and ROOMKEY condition form the join I get almost all the records back but again it gets stuck...

Comment: In that case it might be faster to create a temp #ROOMUSAGE table, add the index and use the temp table in the CTE.

Comment: Thanks Lieven, using a temporary table drastically improved performance.